# Azure Storage - Handle cross partition updates

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a question about a best-practice when working with the Azure Table service.

Imagine a table called Customers. Imagine several other tables, split into a vast amount of partitions. In these tables, there are CustomerName fields.

In the case that a Customer changes his name... Then I update the corresponding record in the Customers table. In contrast to a relational database, all the other columns in the other table are (obviously) not updated.

What is the best way to make sure that all the other tables are also updated? It seems extremely inefficient to me to query all tables on the CustomerName, and subsequently update all these records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing the CustomerName multiple times across tables there is no magic about it, you will need to find those records and update the CustomerName field on them as well.

Since it is quite an inefficient operation, you can (and should) do this "off-transaction". Meaning, when you perform your initial "Name Change" operation, push an item onto a queue and have a worker perform the "Name Change". Since there is no web response / user waiting anxiously for the worker to complete the fact that it is ridiculously inefficient is inconsequential.

This is a primary design pattern for implementing eventual consistency within distributed systems.

Comment: It's this requirement to do changes like this manually that make Azure Table Storage fast at what it does

Comment: The concept of "eventual consistency" definitely sounds very interesting. Thanks for the insight.